# Changing all elements in vector(list, deque...) using C++11 Lambda functions

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    std::vector< int > obj;
    obj.push_back( 10 );
    obj.push_back( 20 );
    obj.push_back( 30 );
    std::for_each( obj.begin(), obj.end(), []( int x )
    { 
        return x + 2; 
    } );
    for( int &v : obj )
        std::cout << v << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The result is : 10, 20, 30

i want to change all elements in vector (obj), using Lambda functions of new C++11 standard.

This is the code of implementation `for_each` function:

```
template<class InputIterator, class Function>
Function for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function f)
{
    for ( ; first!=last; ++first )
        f(*first);
    return f;
}
```

*first passed by value and cope of element is changed, what is the alternative of `for_each` i must use that i have a result: 12, 22, 32 ?

Comment: You need to use lambda with references. I don't know the exact syntax, but it was something like: `[&](int x){ ..}`

Comment: @KirilKirov The `&` inside of `[]` captures the surrounding environment (local variables) by reference. What he needs is just a reference for the input argument: `[](int &x)`.

Comment: @ChristianRau - thanks. I haven't examined the new standard yet, I just have read some things in wikipedia and I don't remember all of that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> i want to change all elements in vector (obj), using Lambda functions of new C++11 standard.

You've to do this :

```
std::for_each( obj.begin(), obj.end(), [](int & x)
{                                          //^^^ take argument by reference
   x += 2; 
});
```

In *your* (not my) code, the return type of the lambda is *deduced* as `int`, but the return value is ignored as nobody uses it. That is why  there is no return statement in my code, and the return type is deduced as `void` for this code.

By the way, I find the range-based `for` loop less verbose than `std::for_each` for this purpose:

```
for( int &v : obj )  v += 2;
```

Comment: You must say `return` in your lambda body if the function is to return anything.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: Lambda doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 8):

You should use `transform`:

```
std::transform( obj.begin(), obj.end(), obj.begin(), []( int x )
{ 
    return x + 2; 
} );
```

Comment: I think `for_each` is just as clear, `transform` makes more sense when you're destination is not the source. In any case, if we're talking "should"'s, I think this is what should be done: `for(auto& x : obj) x += 2;`

Comment: I think both `std::transform()` and the range-based for-loop are good code here. `std::transform()` says more semantically, and `for` talks less period. So you can argue either way.

Answer (score 7):

Pass the argument by **reference** and modify the reference:

```
std::for_each( obj.begin(), obj.end(), [](int & x){ x += 2; } );
//                                        ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 3):

```
std::for_each( obj.begin(), obj.end(), []( int& x )
{ 
     x += 2; 
} );
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the already existing (and perfectly correct) answers, you can also use your existing lambda function, that returns the result instead of modifying the argument, and just use `std::transform` instead of `std::for_each`:

```
std::transform(obj.begin(), obj.end(), obj.begin(), []( int x )
{
    return x + 2;
} );
```